# Project file getting cleared when adding new file VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 11 Pro. I have a large-ish Winforms project. Recently I started having trouble adding new files to the project.

I'll try to add a new class by right-clicking in Solution Explorer. The Add New Item form pops up, I'll enter the class name, click Add and I'll get an error pop up that just says

"The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2."

The new file does not get added. I close the Add New Item form. Now my Project file is empty. Something happened during the error to delete the contents of my project file. I'm using Git and my client shows that everything was deleted so I just undo the changes in the project file so I haven't lost anything yet.

I'll try again and usually I can add a file. Then at some point I'll go through this again. I've rebooted my machine many times.

Anyone have any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The same error message also frequently appears in my VS 2019. Generally it happened during check in dan publishing proess. The workaround I did was to restart the application (VS 2019), and magicaly it solved my problem. But it doesn't prevent the issue not to happen again in the future.